# Updating CustomXMLPart

Tags: vba, ms-word, vsto

Has anyone successfully updated an existing `CustomXMLPart` using VBA or VSTO? I kept tinkering with it for some time, but it appears to crash Word even for the simplest of update operations. Here is minimal code that crashes Word for me:

```
Sub def()
    Dim x As CustomXMLPart
    Set x = ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts.Add("<a>First</a>")
    Debug.Print x.XML
    
    Dim x2 As CustomXMLNode
    Set x2 = x.SelectSingleNode("/")
    x2.Text = "Second"  'This line crashes Word application for me
    Debug.Print x.XML
End Sub
```

I just want to replace the original XML that I stored in `x` with the new value.

Comment: https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/08/23/custom-xml-parts-word-addins/ or https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/15176-customxmlparts-selectbynamespace.html show good examples

Comment: “Has anyone successfully updated an existing CustomXMLPart using VBA?” Yes, frequently. But if you are attempting to replace the root node you can’t. You have to delete the xml part and replace it. The methods in the object model are designed for retrieving and updating the values of individual nodes.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt: Oh that's what I was trying to avoid. Thanks for the input.